# CakeEmail and SMTP Error 535

Tags: cakephp, smtp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using cakephp 2.3.0 and i want send email using devocot + postfix. SMTP work fine because i have installed roundCube and hi received emails and sends emails.

```
class EmailConfig {
public $default = array(
    'host' => 'poczta.example.com',
    'port' => 25,
    'auth' => 'plain',
    'username' => 'username@poczta.example.com',
    'password' => '**********',
    'tls' => true,
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('username@poczta.example.com' => 'Username'),
    'returnPath' => 'username@poczta.example.com',
    'layout' => false,
    'emailFormat' => 'html',
    'template' => 'only_text',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

}

Code for send emails:

```
        try {
            $oEmail->reset();
            $oEmail->config('default');
            $oEmail->to(preg_replace('/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i', '' , trim($v['Email']['email']) ));
            $oEmail->subject($subject);
            $content = str_replace('${id}', md5($v['Email']['id']), $context);
            $content = str_replace('queueId', $queueId, $content);
            $oEmail->viewVars(array('email' => $content));
            if($oEmail->send()) {
                $last = $v['Email']['id'];
                $send++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->out($e->getMessage());
        }
```

And i see i console:

```
SMTP Error: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
```

So quick test with telnet:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 poczta.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo testing
250-poczta.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

So please help me how i sent email using cake ?
EDIT: i have tls in email config file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `tsl` as you have it in your config, it is `tls`

Comment: Can you connect with any other tool? Check the ports, the host name, password and if actually you need to use tls